# Django Slugs as principal url

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following, so that the profile of each registered user can be seen as follows:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/username/

I was able to achieve this, the problem is when wanting to create another page, for example
http://127.0.0.1:8000/explore/

Django consider "explore" as a user and throw me a **404 error**.

this is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<slug:slug>/", PerfilView.as_view(), name="perfil"),
    path("explore/", UserListView.as_view(), name="explore"),
]
```

Am I doing it the right way or am I unable to do this with django?

Regads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should swap the two `path(…)`: if you visit `explore/` it will first match with the `PerfilView` since the slug can take `'explore'` as value.

You thus should rewrite the `urlpatterns` to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #       ↓ first explore
    path('explore/', UserListView.as_view(), name='explore'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PerfilView.as_view(), name='perfil'),
]
```

This also means that you can not use `explore` as a slug here, since then it will match with the `UserListView`.